# async api call function seems to work until test

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get some exchange data and use it for some logic. I thought the most straight forward idea would be to use a function where I could pass the different pairs I may want, there are many per exchange. If I console log inside the function when the data ends everything works find. When i try and get the response when it is ready I get undefined, please see the commented console log and my last line.

I understand that I am missing something with async and the way it works.

```
const https = require('https');

async function binancePairPrice (binancePair) {
    
    let url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker';
    let queryString = '?symbol='

    https.get(url+queryString+binancePair,(res) => {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    
    let binanceBookTicker = '';
    let binanceBookTickerJson = 

    res.on('data', data => {
        binanceBookTicker += data;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        binanceBookTickerJson = JSON.parse(binanceBookTicker);
        //console.log(binanceBookTickerJson);
        return (binanceBookTickerJson)
    });
});
};

binancePairPrice('BTCUSDT').then(console.log);
```

day one javascript coming from python. This is quite a step from what I am used to writing. Any docs or links would be appreciated too.

thansk

Answer (score 0):

https.get doesn't return something that can be promisified, so you can't await it.

You can do something else which is wrapping the https.get call within a Promise and then await it when calling binancePairPrice.

```
 const https = require('https')

 async function binancePairPrice (binancePair) {
   let url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker';
   let queryString = '?symbol='

   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    https.get(url, res => {

        let binanceBookTicker = '';
        let binanceBookTickerJson = 

        res.on('data', data => {
          binanceBookTicker += data;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
          resolve() = >
          {
             binanceBookTickerJson = JSON.parse(binanceBookTicker);
             return (binanceBookTickerJson)
          }
        });
     }) 
  })
}

(async () => await binancePairPrice('BTCUSDT))()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `binancePairPrice` function doesn't wait for the `end` callback to happen and therefore just carries on and returns `undefined`.

You need to return a `Promise` and then resolve the promise with the value you want to return from the function.

[Promise basics](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)

[Using the Promise() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#using_the_promise_constructor)

```
async function binancePairPrice (binancePair) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker';
        let queryString = '?symbol=';

        https.get(url+queryString+binancePair,(res) => {
            console.log(res.statusCode);

            let binanceBookTicker = '';
            let binanceBookTickerJson = 

            res.on('data', data => {
                binanceBookTicker += data;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                binanceBookTickerJson = JSON.parse(binanceBookTicker);
                //console.log(binanceBookTickerJson);
                resolve(binanceBookTickerJson)
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have spent a good many hours now trying to figure out promises. They weren't lying when they said JS was tough.

`code`

(async () => {
    
    const btcUsdtPrice = await binancePairPrice('BTCUSDT');
    console.log(btcUsdtPrice)

})


`code`

My end goal is to display the variable once it is recieved, there are a total of 10 of them. 

Why is my program ending before the value is returned? 
thansk

Comment: "Why is my program ending before the value is returned?", because you're not telling it to wait. If you make a `new Promise`, it will essentially wait until you `resolve` or `reject` it.